# Getting Expected '/' and instead saw ''

Tags: reactjs, jslint

I am using VS Code Editor with JShint and JShint is showing a warning in second div `<div> some text </div>`. It doesnot show any warnings if I give `<div> some text <div/>`. The warning is - (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.div: React.DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>
Expected '/' and instead saw ''. (expected_a_b)jslint(expected_a_b)

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `<div> some text </div>`

Comment: the code you suggested is showing that warning.

Comment: You have a jslint tag but mention jsHint (with an "H") in your question. I'd assume it's jsLint from the error, but want to confirm. Quick answer? **JSLint doesn't like React's JSX.** Conventionally [you'll need to use eslint](https://eslint.org/) for React, not JSLint.